# How to store a .cer file in the keychain macOS (objective c)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, certificate, keychain

I need to store a root certificate (for the browser) in the keychain of macOS with an application built in Objective C. Is there an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

sorry, but I mean by code (objective C). This should be a MAC OS app which generates a CSR based of a private/public key.

I used this sample https://github.com/ateska/ios-csr/, but when I check the csr generated with this code, it has an invalid signature. why?

Answer (score -1):

Simple. After downloading the .cer file you just double-click it, that should register it in the Keychain application.  If that doesn't work, then just open Keychain, to my Certificates, and drag and drop it into the list.